# Can I use the Twig template engine?

Tags: 7, theming

I do a lot of [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) development and I like their templating language.
[Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), the [new templating engine in Drupal 8](https://drupal.org/node/1906384), looks very much like it.

How can I use Twig in Drupal 7 or even Drupal 6?

Comment: There's a [sandbox module for Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/sandbox/ReneB/1075966), I don't think there's a D6 solution out there but I might be wrong

Comment: Was the sandbox module enough? Write an answer and accept it, so this question is considered closed.

Comment: Not really. I'm not looking for experimental stuff. Though I think it's unlikely that this will ever be answered satisfactory. So if @Clive formulates an answer along the lines of "nothing stable, but here's some sand", I'd have to accept it.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling No forced-accepts over here ;) I'd save leave it open-ended, at some point when D8 is out in the wild someone will have a stable solution and then it'll be this q's time to shine!

Comment: @clive, judging on the upvotes, there's at least 5 of us in the world, that would love to see this. :-)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling Anything that brings a bit of the real-world back into Drupal 6/7 is awesome as far as I'm concerned!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can, here is an article about my own experience with it, working with Bootstrap http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2015/develop-with-twig-in-drupal-7

So http://www.drupal.org/project/tfd7 is the way to go if you want to write template files with Twig syntax, it must be moved to `theme/engines`. 
Note that development is now happening at https://github.com/TFD7/TFD7 and documentation is at http://tfd7.rocks.

Don't be confused with the project https://drupal.org/project/twig, unfortunately, it is only an input filter because modules cannot provide theme engines in Drupal 7 (due to license reasons it seems).

Comment: When I upgrade my D6 site to D7, this will work for me. Till then I'll keep this open, in case a D6 solution shows up. For now, "just" the upvote. Thanks