# Is there any problem using Twig?

Tags: 7, theming

Im starting a new big project with D7, so it will contains a lot of contrib / custom modules. It will be preferable to use the theme engine [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). What are the problems that could present later? anyone tried twig with D7 and have some big trouble using some of the contrib modules or any other further issues?

Comment: @clive, i don't think it's a duplicate of the question : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72896/can-i-use-the-twig-template-engine-in-drupal-6-7 there, the user asked for ability to use or not Twig on D7. For me I know that this is possible, im just asking if there is any future problem when using twig on D7? thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid Q+A isn't suitable for polling like this; if you have a specific question (e.g. "I have installed Twig in Drupal 7, how do I get the foo working with the bar module?") that'd be great, but we can't have open-ended questions that don't have a specific answer. There are thousands of modules, hopefully it's clear why it wouldn't be a good use of resources here to work out if the Twig engine is compatible with all of them

Comment: `I'm just asking if there is any future problem when using twig on D7.` **sorry but... we are not psychics**. Without knowing all the modules you are going to use and how you're going to use twig, it's impossible to answer that question. Furthermore, I doubt there are many people here who have used twig with D7 to begin with.

Comment: If it's not a duplicate, it would be closed for being too broad.